# Ubuntu 14.04 Network Manager options sometimes become disabled?

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

Sometimes my network manager options get disabled and I have to reboot the computer in order to be able to change them again. Google searches have not been much help. Anyone else have this issue?

Also I've seemed to have a lot of various annoying little issues with the network manager in the past few years I've been using linux. Is there an alternative to network manager that maybe works better?

Screen shot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK24e.png